# Loop through list of URLs using .Open (Parsing JSON in VBA)

Tags: json, vba, parsing

The "reference URL list" part of the code is where I can drop an individual URL in and the code works fine. But I'd like to make the code more flexible where I can loop through my list of URLs (ideally only changing that portion of my code, or perhaps another small tweak). Here is the code:

```
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", "reference URL list"
MyRequest.Send

Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)
```

I realize there are multiple ways to approach this -- though I can't find specific information that will slightly augment my approach. I really appreciate the help.

Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want. The key idea is to use an Array to hold the list of website you want to send an HTTP request.

You don't have to use an array typed into VBA as I show below, you could also use a `Range` in Excel.

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub HTTP_Req()
    Dim MyRequest As Object: Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    'Add all Urls you want to send a HTTP request to, in an Array
    Dim MyUrls: MyUrls = Array("www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.bing.com")
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Json As Object

    For i = LBound(MyUrls) To UBound(MyUrls)
        With MyRequest
            .Open "GET", MyUrls(i)
            .Send
            Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)
            'Do something with the JSON object here
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @RyanWildry -- works perfect. The last part of my puzzle is looping through JSON text (and parsing) and stopping the loop once there are no further JSON strings (unknowable number in each string set). So, basically just some type of loop that will allow me to stop once there are no additional strings (I have the parsing ,etc. completed). I've seen "loop until/while" suggestions for data embedded in excel rows/columns -- but the fact that I am going to a webpage and pulling down JSON has made this more difficult for me.

Comment: If you have another question, please feel free to start a new question. We are always willing to help. Is the initial question is closed?

Comment: Great, make sure to mark as complete so others know it has been answered. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers